# magento 2.2.2 - How to transfer the product thumbnail to the left side

Tags: magento2, product-images, less-css, thumbnail

How can i set thumbnail images to the left side? I set thumbnail image to vertical in view.xml but it displays a thumbnail image right side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you want to set the slider on the right side: -**

**1) Find the file**
            `"app/design/frontend/[Your_Theme]/[Your_Theme]/etc/view.xml"`
      and look for these lines:

```
<vars module="Magento_Catalog">

<!- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start ->
        <var name="gallery">
```

**Edit the line:**

```
<var name="navdir">horizontal</var>
```

**For:**

```
<var name="navdir">vertical</var>
```

**If you want to set slider on Left side:-**

**Step 1.** **Find the file** `"app/design/frontend/[Your_Theme]/[Your_Theme]/etc/view.xml"` and look for these lines:

```
<vars module="Magento_Catalog">

<!- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start ->
        <var name="gallery">
```

**Edit the line:**

```
<var name="navdir">horizontal</var>
```

**For:**

```
<var name="navdir">vertical</var>
```

**Step 2.**

**Put below code in custom.css**

```
app/design/frontend/[Your_Theme]/[Your_Theme]/web/css
```

**To see Immidiate changes put this code in pub's custom.css**

```
pub/static/frontend/[Your_Theme]/[Your_Theme]/en_US/css
```

**Add this line at the end of your css**

```
.product.media .gallery-placeholder .fotorama__stage{ left: 0 !important; }
.product.media .gallery-placeholder .fotorama__nav-wrap--vertical.fotorama__nav-wrap{ right: 0; text-align: right;}
.product.media .gallery-placeholder .fotorama__nav--thumbs{float: right;}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaimin for this code.this code is working but  How can i customize .less css file for this?