# move left product gallery on product page

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, slider, gallery-image

How to move the slider to the left of the main picture?

[image]

Comment: just by saying him My dear slider please move to left :)

Comment: From image how community can help you please add proper details, its better to provide link of the site so any one look it and suggest you how it would be possible.

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad this is standard magento 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this link

> [magento 2.2.2 - How to transfer the product thumbnail to the left side](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206472/magento-2-2-2-how-to-transfer-the-product-thumbnail-to-the-left-side)

Modify your theme view.xml file

```
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">
      <var name="gallery">
        <var name="navdir">vertical</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->   
     </var>        
</vars>
```

also this your css file

```
.product.media .gallery-placeholder .fotorama__stage{ left: 0 !important; }
.product.media .gallery-placeholder .fotorama__nav-wrap--vertical.fotorama__nav-wrap{ right: 0; text-align: right;}
.product.media .gallery-placeholder .fotorama__nav--thumbs{float: right;}
```

Comment: This method causes a bug. If the scroll is clamped in the thamb and held up and down, then the scroll will be lag, but if you hold and move the mouse a little to the left or gently, the scroll will not lag

Comment: that is css thing than  that needs debug from console , the proper way to move something position is by xml , and the way i added i think will work.

Answer (score 0):

**you can easily do it by css, Please add this following css in your existing css file:**

```
.fotorama__stage__shaft.fotorama__grab {
    margin-left: -120px !important;
}
```